# ASP.net - C# Set input type: datetime-local to current date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetime-format, bootstrapping

This is how I declared the text field on my aspx file:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="inputDate" runat="server">
```

and on my aspx.cs file's page load:

```
inputDate.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

My goal is that when the page loads, inputDate field contains the current date with this "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt" format

but it doesn't work. Nothing's happening.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Did you get any result? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, nothing's happening.

Comment: @Katherine you probably need to compile your solution first. Press CTRL+SHIFT+B and try reload the page.

Comment: Hi! thanks! this one's solved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The input `datetime-local` requires letter T in uppercase for date-time.
Read here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html

Example: 2016-03-23T05:47:48

so you could do something like this:

```
var localDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").Replace(' ','T'); 
inputDate.Value = localDateTime;
```

Comment: You can just add the T to the format specifier. `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm`

Answer (score 3):

html5 input datetime-local

```
var localDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("s"); 
inputDate.Value = localDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with date format, you can use the overloaded version of [DateTime.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx), mentioned below.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It'll enforce your specified format irrespective of what culture setting your server machine has.

Answer (score -1):

In a classic ASP.NET WebForm you can try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
}
```

Also, instead of `TextBox` you can use ASP.NET `Label` control for read-only functionality. This will return the `DateTime` value pertinent to the server time zone. In order to implement a Universal Time use:

```
TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

Then you can apply `AddHours()` function to adjust for the difference in time zones.

Hope this may help.

Comment: This not open datetime selector.